# Why do some big extension companies choose not to use repositories while others do

Tags: magento2

We are currently installing extensions from different companies on our new M2 site.

Some companies (not gonna call names, don't know if that's allowed) just have you 
 `composer require` their repository so you don't have to manually download any `.zip` files, composer does everything for you.

While others, you have to download the `.zip` file of the extension and `composer require` path to the zip files.

I am curious, why companies would possibly not choose to use repositories for client convenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Customer A's composer packages need to be different from Customer B's. Presumably, they only want people to be able to access what they've actually purchased, and that's not a trivial problem. Most companies that don't probably lack either the size or the expertise to pull it off.

There is [Private Packagist](https://packagist.com/) to power it, but it's *expensive* (billed per customer, per month).

Or they could home-grow something, either manually generating the composer repositories after each purchase (slow and a lot of overhead), or scripting the process (like Magento Marketplace does--but a lot of work to implement).

Any way about it, it's not as easy as "just set up composer", and that's why many vendors don't.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Great answer, thank you!:)